# ISTEVEN MULTI SELECT is clearing selected options when making request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using **isteven multi select** with JS, but when I select a name and then search for another name, a request is made, but the request is deselecting the name that was selected. How to fix? And sorry for the bad English.
Below is some of my code.

```
        $scope.searchChanged = function() {                                                
            if ( $scope.inputLabel.labelFilter.length < vMinSearchLength && $scope.inputLabel.labelFilter.length > 0 ) {
                return false;
            }                
            $scope.updateFilter();
        }

        $scope.updateFilter = function()
        {      
            // we check by looping from end of input-model
            $scope.filteredModel = [];
            var i = 0;

            if ( typeof $scope.inputModel === 'undefined' ) {
                return false;                   
            }

            for( i = $scope.inputModel.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {

                // if it's group end, we push it to filteredModel[];
                if ( typeof $scope.inputModel[ i ][ attrs.groupProperty ] !== 'undefined' && $scope.inputModel[ i ][ attrs.groupProperty ] === false ) {
                    $scope.filteredModel.push( $scope.inputModel[ i ] );
                }
                
                // if it's data 
                var gotData = false;
                if ( typeof $scope.inputModel[ i ][ attrs.groupProperty ] === 'undefined' ) {                        
                    
                    // If we set the search-key attribute, we use this loop. 
                    if ( typeof attrs.searchProperty !== 'undefined' && attrs.searchProperty !== '' ) {

                        for (var key in $scope.inputModel[ i ]  ) {
                            if ( 
                                typeof $scope.inputModel[ i ][ key ] !== 'boolean'
                                && String( $scope.inputModel[ i ][ key ] ).toUpperCase().indexOf( $scope.inputLabel.labelFilter.toUpperCase() ) >= 0                                     
                                && attrs.searchProperty.indexOf( key ) > -1
                            ) {
                                gotData = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }                        
                    }
                    // if there's no search-key attribute, we use this one. Much better on performance.
                    else {
                        for ( var key in $scope.inputModel[ i ]  ) {
                            if ( 
                                typeof $scope.inputModel[ i ][ key ] !== 'boolean'
                                && String( $scope.inputModel[ i ][ key ] ).toUpperCase().indexOf( $scope.inputLabel.labelFilter.toUpperCase() ) >= 0                                     
                            ) {
                                gotData = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }                        
                    }

                    if ( gotData === true ) {    
                        // push
                        $scope.filteredModel.push( $scope.inputModel[ i ] );
                    }
                }

                // if it's group start
                if ( typeof $scope.inputModel[ i ][ attrs.groupProperty ] !== 'undefined' && $scope.inputModel[ i ][ attrs.groupProperty ] === true ) {

                    if ( typeof $scope.filteredModel[ $scope.filteredModel.length - 1 ][ attrs.groupProperty ] !== 'undefined' 
                            && $scope.filteredModel[ $scope.filteredModel.length - 1 ][ attrs.groupProperty ] === false ) {
                        $scope.filteredModel.pop();
                    }
                    else {
                        $scope.filteredModel.push( $scope.inputModel[ i ] );
                    }
                }
            }                

            $scope.filteredModel.reverse();  
            
            $timeout( function() {                    

                $scope.getFormElements();               
                
                // Callback: on filter change                      
                if ( $scope.inputLabel.labelFilter.length > vMinSearchLength ) {

                    var filterObj = [];

                    angular.forEach( $scope.filteredModel, function( value, key ) {
                        if ( typeof value !== 'undefined' ) {                   
                            if ( typeof value[ attrs.groupProperty ] === 'undefined' ) {                                                                    
                                var tempObj = angular.copy( value );
                                var index = filterObj.push( tempObj );                                
                                delete filterObj[ index - 1 ][ $scope.indexProperty ];
                                delete filterObj[ index - 1 ][ $scope.spacingProperty ];      
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    if($scope.prevSearch !== $scope.inputLabel.labelFilter){
                        $scope.onSearchChange({ 
                        data: 
                            {
                                keyword: $scope.inputLabel.labelFilter, 
                                result: filterObj 
                            } 
                         });
                        $scope.prevSearch = $scope.inputLabel.labelFilter;
                    }
                }
            },0);
        };
```

I want to ensure that when making a request, it does not deselect the name that is selected.